# Change class name of header when hovering

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the class name of my header when I hover over it. The class name when NOT hovering is ".l-header.pos_fixed.bg_**transparent**.shadow_wide", but I'd like to rename it when hovering to ".l-header.pos_fixed.bg_**solid**.shadow_wide".

Is this possible?

EDIT: Maybe a bit more background information: I want to change the header of https://pinkypromise.pictures to the header of, for example, https://pinkypromise.pictures/contact when hovering on the home page.

Comment: You don't want to change the class name, just use the `hover` pseudo selector: `my-class:hover`

Comment: Also I would suggest reading up on the basics of CSS :)

Comment: I tried the following:`<script>
$(‘.l-header.pos_fixed.bg_transparent.shadow_wide’).hover(
function(){$(this).toggleClass(‘.l-header.pos_fixed.bg_solid.shadow_wide’);}
);" );
</script>`

Comment: @inorganik, I know that's possible but there are a lot of classes and styles attached to the two different class names so a lot of things would change with them.

Comment: In that case think about the structure of your CSS - instead of applying mulitple classes use SCSS `@extend` on a new class or add one class with `!important`s on properties you want to override. It's also possible to write selectors without `!importants` to override properties

Comment: @Breadhead So just change the selector for the hovered state from `.l-header.pos_fixed.bg_solid.shadow_wide` to `.l-header.pos_fixed.bg_solid.shadow_wide, .l-header.pos_fixed.bg_transparent.shadow_wide:hover`. Done.

Comment: @MrLister I don't exactly know what you mean. Currently there are no selectors for the hovered state of `.l-header.pos_fixed.bg_solid.shadow_wide`.

Comment: Please see edit of the main question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I thought only the logo should change.
I see you site is using jQuery.

When I enter this in the console it seems to work fine:

```
jQuery('.l-header.pos_fixed.bg_transparent.shadow_wide').mouseenter(function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('bg_transparent').addClass('bg_solid');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('bg_transparent').removeClass('bg_solid');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Top, graag gedaan ;)!

Comment: Wellicht een domme vraag, maar hoe voeg je deze jQuery-code toe aan de website? Bij het invoeren van de code in de console, zie jij ook de tekst op de homepage naar beneden springen?

Comment: Eh, heren, ik weet wel dat er nog geen nederlandse SO is, maar kunnen we ons toch een beetje inhouden aub qua taalgebruik. Dank u.

Comment: The text shifting down is because of the how the theme works when scrolling down I think.  Therefore you wanna remove the padding.  @media (min-width: 1001px){    .header_hor .sidebar_none .l-header.pos_fixed + .l-main .l-section:first-child { padding-top: 0; }  }  .  But be careful, it might break other theming of your site.

Comment: And your question about the not working jQuery. 
- Be sure it's loaded after the element (in this case the element is with the header that `.l-header.pos_fixed.bg_transparent.shadow_wide`  class). 
- Or you wrap the code within a   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {          });  
- And I doubt it but, if this header is build up by javascript, you need to load this code after that is finished.

Comment: Breadhead , again it's has to do with the order of the code. This change should be within the same .css file or loaded after :).  
It's nasty but you can try to add an extra selector, to make it more specfic:    @media (min-width: 1001px){  .header_hor .sidebar_none .l-header.pos_fixed + .l-main .l-content .l-section:first-child {  padding-top: 0; }}

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, it is possible to change class names based on events (hover, in this case), but you will need javascript for that. You can't achieve this with pure css.

As others have mentioned, it is usually a better approach to have a css rule with the `:hover` pseudo-class. But also be aware that you might have problems with the intended result in touch devices.

A good source of information for these rules is Mozilla Developer Network. Please have a look at the [full documentation for `:hover`'s pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) on MDN.

Comment: The simplest form would be using plain JS (without any external library):
`var el = document.getElementsById('someId');
el.onmouseover = function() {
  el.classList.remove('bg_solid');
  el.classList.add('bg_transparent');
};
el.onmouseout = function() {
  el.classList.remove('bg_transparent');
  el.classList.add('bg_solid');
};`.
For testing purposes you can even copy and paste this in Chrome dev tools console and behavior should work on your test page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the class name on hover, just specify the styles that you want to apply when you hover:

```
header:hover {
  // place the styles that make the background solid here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I already thought about that option, but the other class also contains another logo. Is there a way I can also change that logo when hovering?

Comment: Are the logos a background image?  You can change a background image (or other background property on hover.  `header { background-image: url('yourdefaultimage.jpg'); } header:hover { background-image { url('yourhoverimage.jpg'); } `